# How to plugin return format number float is true after add commad "slice"

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, number-formatting, slice

I have a plugin about format number. You can see demo at [http://jsfiddle.net/nangvabien/Eeukx/5/](http://jsfiddle.net/nangvabien/Eeukx/5)

I input in the textbox : `123456,...,5678 --> 123.456,5678` plugin return format true.

But I'm having some problems, when input in the textbox `123456789 -->1.234.56` or `1234567,--> 123.456`, or `12345678. --> 123.456` I don't know why it's wrong.

But these problems happen after i wrote more commands allow one decimal separator in the textbox.

```
var value = $(this).val(),
patt = /(,.*?,|\..*?\.)/;
if (patt.test(value)) { $(this).val(value.slice(0, -1)); }
```

please help me fix my plugin.